# how to prevent android keyboard from closing on new Activity open

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Android activity with an editText and the keyboard is open

how can I open an activity which part of it is transparent and keep the keyboard open on the former activity

currently the new activity closes the keyboard
can this be done with the same scenario but with fragments?

manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".EditTextActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyPayKeySetupActivityTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"/>

<activity
    android:name=".TransparentActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"/>
```

style:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item> <!-- Or any transparency or color you need -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

EditTextActivity:

```
class EditTextActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_activity)
        findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText).requestFocus()

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, TransparentActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

EditTextActivity Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter text here"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OPEN TRANSPARENT ACTIVITY"/>
```

Comment: Show me your UI when a transparent activity shows up?

Comment: @CôngHải added all relevant UI
Keyboard closes on when TransparentActivity is called